# Mapping from Collection<T> to Collection<T> by convention

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to map from a property of type Collection<T> to another property of type Collection<T> by convention without the need to define the mapping explicitly?

```
class CollectionExample {
    public static void Example() {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
                //.ForMember(dest => dest.Items, member => member.MapFrom(src => src.Items))
            ;
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var foo = new Foo() {
            Items =
            {
                new Foo(),
                new Foo(),
                new Foo()
            }
        };

        var fooDto = mapper.Map<Foo, FooDto>(foo);

        Debug.Assert(fooDto.Items.Count == foo.Items.Count, $"There are only {fooDto.Items.Count} items in the dto object but we expected {foo.Items.Count} items.");
    }

    class Foo {
        public Collection<Foo> Items { get; } = new Collection<Foo>();
    }

    class FooDto {
        public Collection<FooDto> Items { get; } = new Collection<FooDto>();
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the `ForMember(..)` this works. Am I missing something for the convention based method?

Comment: You need either a setter, or the `MapFrom`, whichever you prefer :)

Comment: *Facepalm* Too easy. Please post this as answer so I can mark your comment as solution :-D  And thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either a setter, or the `MapFrom`, whichever you prefer :) That's the case in versions before 10. Check the link in the comment for the behavior in version 10.

Comment: Note: This has been changed with AutoMapper 10 (see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#all-collections-are-mapped-by-default-even-if-they-have-no-setter)