# Automapping a destination collection property with a private set

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public sealed class ParentSource
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<ChildSource> Children { get; }

    public ParentSource(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<ChildSource>();
    }
}

public sealed class ChildSource
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ChildSource(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public sealed class ParentDestination
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<ChildDestination> Children { get; }

    public ParentDestination(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<ChildDestination>();
    }
}

public sealed class ChildDestination
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ChildDestination(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

To my understanding, all I need are the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<ParentSource, ParentDestination>();
CreateMap<ChildSource, ChildDestination>();
```

Call the mapping:

```
var parentSource = new ParentSource("parent");
var childSource = new ChildSource("child");
parentSource.Children.Add(childSource);

var parentDestination = mapper.Map<ParentSource, ParentDestination>(parentSource);
```

The child collection of the destination parent doesn't contain any members unless I add a public setter to the Children property. How can I make this work without a public setter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752261/mapping-from-collectiont-to-collectiont-by-convention?noredirect=1#comment103793183_58752261

Comment: But note that you have no setter at all. A private setter would just work, no `MapFrom` needed.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I decided to go with MapMember from your first link. Thanks!